# Can an infected machine have any security?

Tags: privacy, attacks, memory

Assuming that an attacker can view — but not change — the memory on your machine, can any amount of security be guaranteed?

Also, can privacy be guaranteed for messages in this scenario?

Comment: For example, you can be sure that an attacker — by assumption — cannot change any memory contents, so if that's your goal, you're fine. My point being that "security" does not come in "amounts", but depends heavily on what you are trying to protect against. I think your question would benefit from more context about the security model.

Comment: Simplified - If the attacker is read-only (not likely), let's consider confidentiality as an issue (thread).  "Can privacy be guaranteed for messages" - when all the messages are properly encrypted through end-to-end communication (the machine pass the mesages as they are). As soon you need some operations to do, that coud be tricky (homomorphic encryption still sounds like magic to me)

Comment: @gusto2 I did some research on homomorphic encryption and it seems to be what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: The machine can still be used for `multi-party computation`. Since the attacker can only view the memory content, semi-honest security is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's consider the main tenets of security.

- Confidentiality - Data cannot be read by anyone other than the intended recipient.
- Integrity - Protection from unauthorized modification
- Availability - Self explanatory, the capability to make data available
- Non-repudiation - the quality which ensures that an    action cannot be denied.
- Authentication - The quality that validates files, uers etc are authentic.

In the above five, only confidentiality is affected by an attacker with read only access. So the short answer is, yes, there is some amount of security left.

Privacy cannot be guaranteed as all the factors ensuring confidentiality is readily available for the attacker.